# Compressing and converting a jpg to tiff in Java

Tags: java, image, jpeg, tiff

I have a jpg image and I want to convert it to a tiff file, but when I create the output file from byteArrayOutputStream, the output file has 0 byte length.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String root = "E:\\Temp\\imaging\\test\\";

    File image = new File(root + "0riginalTif-convertedToJpg.JPG");

    byte[] bytes = compressJpgToTiff(image);
    File destination = new File(root + "OriginalJpg-compressedToTiff.tiff");
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(destination);
    fileOutputStream.write(bytes);
}


public static byte[] compressJpgToTiff(File imageFile) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(255);
    ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream = null;
    try {
        File input = new File(imageFile.getAbsolutePath());

        Iterator<ImageWriter> imageWriterIterator = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIF");
        ImageWriter writer = imageWriterIterator.next();
        imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
        writer.setOutput(imageOutputStream);

        ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionType("JPEG");
        param.setCompressionQuality(0.1f);

        BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(input);
        writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), param);
        writer.dispose();
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } finally {
        if (imageOutputStream != null)
            imageOutputStream.close();
        byteArrayOutputStream.close();
    }
}
```

I want to reduce the size of output tiff as much as possible. Is there a better approach? Is it even possible to reduce the size of a tiff image?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) *"I want to reduce the size of output tiff as much as possible."* Why not save it as a JPEG with higher compression?

Comment: Because I want it to be tiff!

Comment: So .. where is the MCVE / SSCCE?

Answer (score 0):

`return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();` but you didn't wirite data to `byteArrayOutputStream`. Look, you just added data to `writer`.

About compression of tiff file, you have already done it with - `param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);`

Comment: I did it: `imageOutputStream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream);
            writer.setOutput(imageOutputStream);`

Answer (score 0):

Your *byteArrayOutputStream* object is getting closed in **finally** block before you converting byteArrayOutputStream to byteArray using `byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` thats why you getting content length to be **0**. So modify your code once as below :

```
public static byte[] compressJpgToTiff(File imageFile) throws Exception {
//Add rest of your method code here
writer.dispose();
byte[] bytesToReturn = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
return bytesToReturn;
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    if (imageOutputStream != null)
        imageOutputStream.close();
    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but obviously that's not the reason.

Comment: In that case just debug yourself line by line and see where stream is getting lost or reaching EOF. But just by seeing your code first thought came that in `finally block which runs before your return statement` closing your stream object than returning toByte part which will obviously have nothing to convert to byte. So recheck again.

Comment: I already did that and still I cant figure it out. The byteArrayOutputStream is never filled in with data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a `imageOutputStream.flush()` before get byteArray:

```
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(input);
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), param);
    writer.dispose();
    imageOutputStream.flush();
    return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
```